# How often can a method be performed on a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a undirected graph G(no self-loops, no multiple edges allowed) with `n >= 3` nodes and without edges.
There is also the following method A:
Add to the graph G a new node v and the three edges `{v,w1},{v,w2} and {v,w3}`.
w1,w2 and w3 are nodes contained already in the original graph (pairwise distinct).

The question is how many times can the method A be exectued (dependent on n), 
if the nodes may not have a `degree > 4`?

My observations: 
Each time the method A is executed we became one more node. This node has already a degree of 3, so this node can be connected by only one more edge. In the same step three other nodes got a +1 higher degree.
I have tested a graph G with n=3 nodes. The method could be executed four times.

This is not homework, it is an old exam question.
So I do not ask for a solution, only for a hint on how to solve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are on the right track.  The graph starts with a "capacity" to add 4*n edges.  Each new node reduces the total edge capacity by 2.   This can be solved with simple algebra.  The only remaining question is can you find a edge assignment scheme which prevents situations where you have enough edge capacity but not enough nodes.

Comment: Let 4n be my goal. I reach it by (3 - 1) * (number of executions). So we have 4n = (2) * #ops. Divide this by 2 gives us #ops = 2n. Like 'ile' mentioned below the correct answer is 2n-1. Does the graph have a specific property which brings me from 2*n to 2*n-1 or is my consideration wrong?

Comment: it is indeed (2n-1). Actually, each edge reduces the capacity by 3 and only after adds 1 to the total capacity. So towards the end, when you have 2 capacity left, you can not "borrow" 1 and subtract 3. So you always get left with 2 capacity, thus -1 to the total 2n.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want a hint, work out the solution for small n, and you should be able to see a generalization to a greater n. You had a good start and you can get to the answer if you work a little more.

For small n's I have the following values starting at n = 3: {5, 7, 9, 11, 13}.

Comment: By your values I would set up the recursion for the number of possible executions A(n) = A(n-1) + 2, n > 3 , A(3) = 5. Which will bring me 2*(n-3) + 5

Comment: @Elternhaus the easier to reason recursion is a[n] = a[n-3] + a[3] + 1, and set a[3] = 5, a[4] = 7, and a[5] = 9.

Comment: This recursion seems to work, because you can now put together all sorts of possible n. You get the recursion backwards through the calculated values, right?

Comment: I don't like this answer, and I should probably delete it... Personally for me, it is easier to construct a[n]=a[n-3]+a[3]+1 rather than a[n]=a[n-1]+2. And then later show that the two recursions are actually same. To construct a[n]=a[n-3]+a[3]+1, you had to just simply work out the cases for n=3,4,5. You would notice that the initial nodes can create 2*n nodes with degrees one.